# Scrollviewer giving issues when converting stack panel to ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

When replacing a StackPanel with a itemControl template suddenly the scrolling did not work properly anymore.

Old:

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="HorizontalScroller"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            CanContentScroll="True" Margin="2.4,0,1.2,0">

            <StackPanel x:Name="spHorizontal" Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="False" 
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="862.4"/>            
        </ScrollViewer>
```

New:

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="HorizontalScroller" Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" CanContentScroll="True" Margin="2.4,0,1.2,0" >

            <!---RegBtns verwijst naar de ObservableCollection die alle registration buttons bevat-->
            <ItemsControl Name="ItemControlRegistration" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=RegBtns}" Width="834.4">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="spHorizontal" Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                                    Width="834,4" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>                       
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--template  custom style button: -->
                        <Button x:Name="RegistrationTestButton" Content="TEST" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Width="151" 
                                Margin="10,0,5,0" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleRegistration}" 
                                Click="RegistrationTestButton_Click">                              
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>             
        </ScrollViewer>
```

The problem is it does not display the button completely. Meaning browsing from 1-5 and pressing right does not show 2-6 directly. 
In other words if i press right i want to see the complete button nr 6 at once. Now it is basically scrolling slow to the right (or left) and parts of the button slowly appear.
When i press i want the next button instantly displayed.

What exactly made these abrupt changes happen?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the scrollViewer into template of ItemsControl? I mean sth like following

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemControlRegistration" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=RegBtns}" Width="834.4">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <ScrollViewer x:Name="HorizontalScroller" Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" CanContentScroll="True" Margin="2.4,0,1.2,0" >
                    <StackPanel x:Name="spHorizontal" Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                                Width="834,4" />
              </ScrollViewer>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>                       
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--template  custom style button: -->
                    <Button x:Name="RegistrationTestButton" Content="TEST" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Width="151" 
                            Margin="10,0,5,0" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleRegistration}" 
                            Click="RegistrationTestButton_Click">                              
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working. Also i have to be able to access this scrollviewer from code behind.

Comment: Thats exactly what i have done but having troubles accesing the scrollviewer now from the codebehind. I need this to set the LineLeft and LineRight properties to certain buttons. "VisualTree of ItemsPanelTemplate must contain a Panel. 'System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer' is not a Panel. wpf"